# Update duplicate latitude values by iteratively increasing margin

Tags: sql, oracle

I have lat and long columns in an Oracle database table stored as regular numbers. 
Some of which are duplicates. I'd like a way to add a very small margin to either column to eliminate duplication. Problem is, for each identical  pair the number of duplicate records might vary. In this case I have to adjust the margin I add iteratively for each  pair.

example:

```
 ID |    LAT | LONG
==================
1   |     1  |  1
2   |     1  |  1
3   |     1  |  1
```

in this case, I'd like to add a margin of .0003 to either column to eliminate the duplication, but I can't just blindly add that .0003 to IDs 2 and 3 because they would still be duplicates, so I have to do original_value + (margin*i) for i in (0...number of duplicate rows)

so I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
ID | LAT | LONG
1 |  1   |   1
2 | 1.0003 | 1
3 | 1.0006 | 1
```

How do I do this in SQL? I can mimic imperative programming apparently with cursors but it does not seem to be the SQL way. Can I somehow achieve this with INSERT INTO SELECT?

Comment: What is your motivation for this?

Comment: Huh?  What is a "margin?"  Please show some tables, data, expected results, etc.

Comment: Okay, I added a toy example...my motivation is to have those lat/long be slightly apart when viewed on a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your exact data looks like, but suppose you have this table, called `tbl`:

```
        ID        LAT        LON
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         20         25
         2         30         33
         3         30         33
         4         55         60
         5         55         60
         6         55         60
```

You could run the following:

```
select  id,
        case when rn > 1 then lat+rn-1 else lat end as lat,
        lon
from(
select  t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by lat, lon order by id) as rn
from    tbl t
) x;
```

To get:

```
        ID        LAT        LON
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         20         25
         2         30         33
         3         31         33
         4         55         60
         5         56         60
         6         57         60
```

Notice how IDs 2 and 3 were dups, and IDs 4, 5, and 6, were dups. They are no longer exact dups because the `lat` value has increased, sequentially, to make the rows not duplicates. They go up by one for each next duplicate.

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef959/1/0

**Edit (based on your edit)**

```
select  id,
        case when rn > .0003 then lat+rn-.0003 else lat end as lat,
        lon
from(
select  t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by lat, lon order by id)*.0003 as rn
from    tbl t
) x;
```

The above will ascend by .0003 rather than 1.

See new fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/21506/6/0

Comment: I did this to your fiddle and it achieved my desired result too:
   case when rn > 1 then (lat+(0.003*(rn-1))) else lat end as lat,

thanks a lot!